# Add Role to a User just as they Register

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm developing an application for a simple Church.

I have a few sets of User Roles e.g. Admin, Priest, Volunteer, Lay User.

I would like to be able for someone to register and them to be assigned the Lay User role straight away. In my current system, they aren't assigned any role.

Here is my code for Registering and trying to assign a the Lay User to the registered person:

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var checkEmail = db.UserProfiles
                .Any(b => (model.Email == b.Email));
            if ((TempData["ErrorEmail"] == null))
            {
                if (!checkEmail)
                {
                    // Attempt to register the user
                    try
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Email = model.Email });
                        AddToLayUser(model.UserName);
                        WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                        return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");

                    }
                    catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["ErrorEmail"] = "Email already in System";
                }

            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    protected void AddToLayUser(String username)
    { 
        var usersInLayUser = new List<UserAndRoles>();

        var userDetails = (from u in db.UserProfiles
                            where u.UserName == username
                            select u);
        UserAndRoles userAndRoles = new UserAndRoles();
        userAndRoles.LayUser = "X";

        userAndRoles.UserId = userDetails.FirstOrDefault().UserId;
        userAndRoles.UserName = userDetails.FirstOrDefault().UserName.ToString();
        usersInLayUser.Add(userAndRoles);
    }
```

I debugged the above and the username is sent to the method and it checks the LINQ statement but after when I checked my database, the user isn't added to the Lay User Role.

Comment: If you want a default role, just set it up in the Database using a trigger or default value for the "Role" column. Usethe OUTPUT syntax to get the ID of the newly added users for it.

Comment: Where do you persist the data?  I dont see any code that is saving the data at all.  Also, are you having a string `"X"` indicate whether a user is a LayUser?  Why not use a bool?

Comment: Are you having code to store the usersInLayUser to DBContenxt?

Comment: @maccettura wow.... its been a long day and you just made me realise I'm using a totally different method than what I should be dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "roleName");
```

More about user roles  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Might help to link to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole(v=vs.110).aspx) and to explain your answer and why you think this will solve the OP's problem

Comment: @maccettura i think that will help i have updated my answer.